# 2009 Toyota Corolla Air Conditioning

Tags: toyota, ac, corolla, air

Whats up everyone: 
I have a 2009 Toyota Corolla. The AC stopped blowing any air whatsoever, unless I went to level 4 (the highest level). Then it would blow the AC air ice cold, as it should. One day, level 4 went bust and now nothing is blowing any air whatsoever - no heat, no outside air, no AC. 
I did my Google search and replaced the blower resistor. 
Once I put the blower resistor in, the AC will turn on - but only on Level 2 - and really weak air flow (at least it is ice cold, but not fixed yet).
What could I be doing wrong? 
Is it the motor that needs to be replaced? 
I assume it is not the fuse since the AC does turn on level 2, although weakly. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What engine do you have? There are differences between the two engines as well as two different manufacturers of parts for the HVAC system. For a general troubleshooting tip, Make sure you have good battery voltage at the blower motor. Make sure you have a good ground on switch selection 4. 4 should be wired straight to ground at the selector switch. If there's voltage drop on the ground side you make have a bad switch or ground. Make sure the resistor has a good ground on the white/black wire. On these Corollas both the resistor and switch share the E4 ground point in the right kick panel.

Comment: @Ben - I bet it's the resistor pack, however good call to diagnose before replacement.